# Getting Intermittent BIP3113E error from IBM Message Broker

Tags: java, web-services, maven, messagebroker

I have deployed a message flow in Message Broker. The flow calls a back-end web service.
Broker has published the deployed flow as a WSDL. I took the WSDL and using Maven, created a test client.
The client works and everything. I can call the flow and get results back.
It's just that about half the calls are successful, and half the time I get this:

Has anyone run into this before?
Thanks

> javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: BIP3113E: Exception detected in
>   message flow HPDTrackingByDate.SOAP Input (broker MB8BROKER)      at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:178)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:119)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:108)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:107)

Comment: what do you mean "half of the calls"? You mean, you randomly get the error by sending the same exact request? Or do they fail while running different requests? If the requests are different - I would suggest identifying and analyzing the failing requests.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I randomly get the error for the same exact request.